# How to hide zero values in SSRS stacked chart data labels

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a stacked bar chart, and some of the stacked values will display the data label for zero values, I have tried the many ways to hide the zero values in stacked chart data labels, But still displaying the Zero value bars.

"Event_Type" resultsets from SQL query in Text format (ie: incident, Service Request , Problem and Change request etc ) and i am using count of those value to display in chart

Tried the following,

```
=IIf(count(fields!Event_Type.Value) = 0, false, true)
=IIF(First(Fields!Event_Type.Value, "DataSet1") Is Nothing, True, False)
=IIF(count(Fields!Event_Type.Value, "DataSet1") = 0, True, False)
=IIF( Sum(Fields!Event_Type.Value)=0, Nothing, Count(Fields!Event_Type.Value) )
```

[image: Sample Result]

Comment: Have you tried removing the Zero value rows from the data source ( Sql query )?

Comment: Event_Type result from SQL query in Text format (ie: incident, Service Request , Problem and Change request etc ) and i am using count of those value to display in chart

Answer (score 4):

Right click on the chart series labels and select series label properties.
In the number formatting, choose number and set Show zero as: to blank value

[image]